# Relying on error code 1062 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is it a good practice to rely on error code 1062 from application code, to make decisions, while inserting in key columns?

Comment: Yeah, the same way you can rely on every other error. What's so special about it?

Comment: Nothing! Just a doubt. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether the error code 1062 (duplicate key) is okay to rely on, yes. It will never change.